# In SharePoint 2007 document is crawled but not coming in the search result

Tags: 2007, search, search-results, crawling, keywordquery

What to do when documents are getting crawled but not coming in the serch result.

I have checked the crawl log and I can see those documents are successfully crawled but in the search result those documents are not coming.
Thanks for the time...

Comment: What type of documents is it ? Word, pdf or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Check Security on the item, are you able to view it?
Check the title and contents of the document, are you using the right search terms to retrieve it?

Are you using MOSS Search or WSS Search? Are you on the OSSSearchResults page or the Results.aspx page?

Comment: I apologies for very late reply..

In library there are two ppt's along with other documents.

1 Bank_DeckQ1.pptx

2 Bank_DeckQ2.pptx

In crawl log these two ppt's are successfully crawled.

When I search using the name of file only one file is coming in the result.

Also when I search using by word "Bank" which is also present inside document and in file name too still no document is coming in the result.

I am checking this on OSSSearchResults page.

We have created content source again and did full crawl but still no luck.

Comment: You may have an issue with the Office iFilters. You can reinstall them then rerun the full crawl.

Comment: but other ppt's are coming in the result..